# Unable to exit C# webbrowser.documentcompleted

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, webbrowser-control

I have to do multiple steps for updating a bunch of webshops, and since every update requires some actions on specfic parts of the shops, this is to be done programmatically.

The webshops get called in a foreach loop, like this: `webbrowser.navigate("UrlStart" + Shop "UrlEnd)`

My webbrowser.documentcompleted is handled by a function: `void WebBrowser1OnDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)`

Inside this function, I have an if-else statement for checking the current URL. I wanted to go with a switch, however the URL is dependent on the current shop, thus the if-else. Some of the actions on the pages require reloading the page, so in this cases I have additional switch stetements for original load/reload.

The structure inside OnDocumentCompleted is like this:

```
if(e.Url.Tostring() == "Page1"){
   switch{
     case1: //Do stuff)
     case2:navigate to Page2 }}
else if(e.Url.Tostring() == "Page2"){
   //Do more stuff
   navigate to Page3
}
else if(e.Url.Tostring() == "Page3"){
   switch{
     case3: // Do stuff
     case4: // Do stuff
     case5: navigate to Page4
}}
else if(e.Url.Tostring() == "Page4"){
switch{
     case6: // Do stuff
     case7: return;}
```

All these steps work, meaning two logins and multiple button clicks on various pages.
However, once I'm on step 7 and the final reload is done, the program just keeps running without doing anything.
I've tried various combinations of break; return; in mutliple places, all I could think of, but the function `WebBrowser1OnDocumentCompleted` is not exited, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: The return should be after the last curly bracket (not before).

Comment: Your are exiting from the event handler here, not from your application. How to exit the aplication depends on the type of application (WinForms? WPF? ...?)

Comment: @jdweng I placed it there for demonstration purposes only, I've tried after the last bracket, in the switch, as an else if none of the URL's match (in combination with navigating to another site), but the function just wouldn't exit.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do, exit the handler so my for each can loop to the next entry and repeat the steps for the next shop, but the handler just keeps on running without doing anything.

Comment: It 's diffucult to help you with just this pseudo code. Can you try to create a [mre]?